# Exclude word on 3 tables join

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables like these:

**product**

```
product_id | name
1          | Pizza Margherita
2          | Pizza Salsiccia
3          | Pizza Marinara
```

**filter_description**

```
filter_id  | name
1          | Mozzarella
2          | Pomodoro
3          | Salsiccia
```

**product_filter**

```
product_id | filter_id
1          | 1
1          | 2
2          | 1
2          | 2
2          | 3
3          | 2
```

I need to join 3 tables and make two queries, the first for all pizza without 'Mozzarella', and the second for all pizza with 'Mozzarella' AND 'Salsiccia'.

Comment: Okay, go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use below query for your criteria

For all pizza without 'Mozzarella'

```
select p.product_id, p.name
from product p 
join product_filter pf using(product_id)
join filter_description fd using(filter_id)
group by p.product_id, p.name
having sum(fd.name = 'Mozzarella') = 0;
```

For all pizza with 'Mozzarella' AND 'Salsiccia'

```
select p.product_id, p.name
from product p 
join product_filter pf using(product_id)
join filter_description fd using(filter_id)
group by p.product_id, p.name
having sum(fd.name = 'Mozzarella') = 1
and sum(fd.name = 'Salsiccia') = 1;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e01582/3)

Answer (score 0):

Variants with `NOT IN` and `IN`

```
-- all pizza without 'Mozzarella'
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE product_id NOT IN(
          SELECT DISTINCT pf.product_id
          FROM product_filter pf
          JOIN filter_description fd ON fd.filter_id=pf.filter_id
          WHERE fd.name='Mozzarella'
        )

-- all pizza with 'Mozzarella' AND 'Salsiccia'.
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE product_id IN(
          SELECT pf.product_id
          FROM product_filter pf
          JOIN filter_description fd ON fd.filter_id=pf.filter_id
          WHERE fd.name IN('Mozzarella','Salsiccia') -- condition 1
          GROUP BY pf.product_id
          HAVING COUNT(fd.name)=2 -- condition 2
        )
```